# What is Layout?

Tags: memory-management, rust

I want to reimplement some stdlib smart pointers in rust (mainly Box) to learn it better, i come from a C background which has the simple `malloc` and `free` functions, but rust's `alloc` and `dealloc` need some `Layout`. What is it? It's not really explained in the docs.

Comment: which docs are you reading? [These](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) docs?

Comment: @kmdreko yeah, those

Comment: you can click on `Layout` in the function signature to get to its page, or you can search for it in the search bar at the top, cheers!

Comment: @kmdreko The OP wasn't totally clear about that, but I suspect the stumbling block is that the docs don't really explain _why_ the layout is needed, especially compared to C whose `malloc` only requires the block size.

Comment: @user4815162342 I mostly commented in case there was confusion how to use the docs. I would've expected different wording if the OP was simply asking why it was necessary. Either way, your answer is very good and will definitely help others with the same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As its documentation says, [`Layout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html) describes a block of memory that is to be allocated or deallocated. In addition to memory size, it specifies alignment and optionally the trailing padding of the block.

C's `malloc` isn't told what alignment to use, so it has to assume worst-case alignment, possibly wasting memory. And even in C one sometimes needs memory of non-standard alignment, for which APIs [outside of standard C](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html) had to be used until [C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc).

One final difference between Rust's and C's allocator interface is that Rust requires the layout to be passed to [`dealloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html#tymethod.dealloc) as well as to [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html#tymethod.alloc) - equivalent to C's `free` requiring the size that was passed to `malloc`. At first this sounds like a disadvantage because the user of the API must track the allocated size in order to be able to deallocate. But it turns out not to be an issue in practice because:

- when allocating a single value such as `Box<T>` or array `Box<[T; n]>`, the size is determined at compile-time and thus known when `Box::drop` is invoked.
- when allocating a dynamic array, such as `Vec<T>`, the capacity of the vector is tracked by the vector itself and thus also available in `Vec::drop`.
- when [boxing a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice), such as `Box<[T]>`, the slice cannot be resized and its capacity is equal to its length and again known to `Box::drop`.

So it turns out that it is the C-style allocation API that results in storing redundant size information. Passing the size to `dealloc` eliminates the redundancy, providing opportunity to save space, especially for small blocks where the size information is a non-negligible percentage of the memory used.

When comparing Rust's allocation interface to that of C, keep in mind that in Rust raw allocation is much more of a specialized tool, used only to implement safe abstractions such as `Box`, `Rc` or `Vec`. Unlike C, where a programmer is routinely expected to invoke `malloc` and `free`, most Rust programmers never need to invoke the global allocator directly.

Comment: Actually, since C11, C gained [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) to handle larger alignments, no need for platform specific APIs any longer there.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, I've now amended the answer to mention it.